# Java getting input from USB Barcode scanner

Tags: java, barcode-scanner

I have Honeywell USB barcode scanner. I want to read input of barcode scanner by using **Java code.**
I got solution by below code but **i dont want to use any gui**.

```
 import java.awt.AWTEvent;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.Toolkit;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

 public class BarcodeScaner extends JFrame {
    private static String strBarcode = "";
    private static JTextField jtBarcode = new JTextField(25);
    public BarcodeScaner() {    
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Capture barcode "));
        getContentPane().add(jtBarcode);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BarcodeScaner br = new BarcodeScaner();
        readBarCode();   
        br.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        br.setVisible(true);
        br.pack();
    }

    private static void readBarCode() {
        // start of listening for barcode events
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new BarcodeAwareAWTEventListener(new BarcodeCapturedListener() {
            @Override
            public void barcodeCaptured(String barcode) {
                strBarcode = barcode;
                System.out.println("====="+barcode);
                jtBarcode.setText(strBarcode);            
            }
        }), AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
        // end of listening for barcode events
    }  
}
```

In above code i have to focus on textbox then only i get scanned value.
I have search in stackoverflow but i didnt get any specific solution.

I also try this below code but still serialEvent is not execute.

```
package scanhandler;


import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

public class ScanHandler implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

    private static CommPortIdentifier   myCommPortIdentifier;
    private static Enumeration          portList;
    private static String               TimeStamp;
    private static String               driverClass;
    private static String               connectionString;
    private static String               comPort;    

    private Connection                  myConnection;
    private InputStream                 myInputStream;
    private Robot                       myRobot;
    private SerialPort                  mySerialPort;
    private Thread                      myThread;


    public ScanHandler() {

        // open serial port
        try {
            TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
            mySerialPort = (SerialPort) myCommPortIdentifier.open("ComControl", 2000);
            //System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": " + myCommPortIdentifier.getName() + " opened for scanner input");
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get serial input stream
        try {
            myInputStream = mySerialPort.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // add an event listener on the port
        try {
            mySerialPort.addEventListener(this);
        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mySerialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        // set up the serial port properties
        try {
            mySerialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            mySerialPort.setDTR(false);
            mySerialPort.setRTS(false);

        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // make a robot to pass keyboard data
        try {
            myRobot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // create the thread
        myThread = new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    // on scan
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        if (event.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {

            StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int c;
            try {

                // append the scanned data onto a string builder
                while ((c = myInputStream.read()) != 10){
                   if (c != 13)  myStringBuilder.append((char) c);
                }               

                // send to keyboard buffer if it the barcode doesn't start with '5'
                if (myStringBuilder.charAt(0) != '5') {

                    for (int i = 0; i < myStringBuilder.length(); i++) {
                        myRobot.keyPress((int) myStringBuilder.charAt(i));
                        myRobot.keyRelease((int) myStringBuilder.charAt(i));
                    }

                // here's the scanned barcode as a variable!
                } else {
                    TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
                    System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": scanned input received:" + myStringBuilder.toString());                    
                }

                // close the input stream
                myInputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read ScanHandler properties
        Properties myProperties = new Properties();
        try {
            myProperties.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
            comPort             = myProperties.getProperty("ScanHandler.comPort");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }              

        try {

            // get our pre-defined COM port
            myCommPortIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(comPort);
            ScanHandler reader = new ScanHandler();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
            System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": " + comPort + " " + myCommPortIdentifier);
            System.out.println(TimeStamp + ": msg1 - " + e);
        }
    };    
}
```

Comment: So you want to do this in a command line only application ?

Comment: yes i want same @nos

Comment: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String myLine = scan.nextLine();`

Answer (score 1):

Please set the scanner to USB Serial mode by using the setting barcode stated in the user's guide.

Then install the serial port device driver of the OS of the machine to which the scanner is connected.

Then you can open the serial port and send commands to the scanner and receive barcode data.